# compile md5 checksum in C but got compile error

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, md5

Tried to follow the example in [SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627723/how-to-create-a-md5-hash-of-a-string-in-c), but when compiling the following, got error:

> $ gcc te.c 
>   te.c: In function ‘main’: 
>   te.c:10:17: error: storage size of ‘context’ isn’t known

Here is the code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>
//#include <md5.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned char digest[16];
    const char* string = "Hello World";
    struct MD5_CTX context;
    MD5Init(&context);
    MD5Update(&context, string, strlen(string));
    MD5Final(digest, &context);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
        printf("%02x", digest[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

By the way, my PC is running ubuntu 12.04 desktop. My gcc version is 4.7.3 and here is the version of libssl-dev

```
dpkg -l libssl-dev
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================
ii  libssl-dev     1.0.1-4ubuntu5 SSL development libraries, header files and
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE1**

Thanks to Sourav Ghosh who pointed out that in the above, the `struct` in `struct MD5_CTX context` should be removed.  Turned out the function name should be changed too, for example `MD5Init` to `MD5_Init`

This is working code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>
//#include <md5.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned char digest[16];
    const char* string = "Hello World";
    MD5_CTX context;
    MD5_Init(&context);
    MD5_Update(&context, string, strlen(string));
    MD5_Final(digest, &context);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
        printf("%02x", digest[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

To compile it, one needs to use `gcc te.c -lssl -lcrypto`.
Thanks to an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295980/md5-reference-error) for this too!

Comment: Where is `struct MD5_CTX` defined?

Comment: I thought it should be defined in openssl/md5.h.  Didn't check though.

Comment: It was able to find the header file, otherwise the compiler will complain it can't find it.

Comment: I don;t think It is a good idea to to edit the question in a way you did as per the latest one. A question, should remain a question. IMHO, you should rollback to the previous version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, (and as [I can see](http://qscan345.sourceforge.net/da/db0/md5_8h_source.html)) `MD5_CTX` is already a `typedef` to a `struct`. You don't need to write `struct MD5_CTX context;`.

Change it to `MD5_CTX context;` and it should work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just realized that too. Will accept your answer in a few minutes since SO is preventing me from doing it now.   By the way,  the functions should be `MD5_Init`, `MD5_Update`, `MD5_Final`, but linker still can't find it when I ran `gcc te.c -lssl`.  Any ideas?

Comment: @codingFun That brings down to the same point as my earlier comment, did you provide the path to the library?

Comment: yes, I think the default should work since if it was able to find the libssl.a (-lssl option in the command line).  Otherwise, the linker will complain it can't find the library.

Comment: @codingFun Can you try providing the path to the library explicitly by using the `-L` option? I don't see any other reason as of now.

Comment: I see the problem: missed crypto  .  This works:   `gcc te.c -lssl -lcrypto`.   Thanks.

Comment: @codingFun I was not aware of the required libraries. So, cant guess. You're welcome, BTW.